# How do I preview a file using InputStream in WebView iOS- swift

Tags: ios, swift, webview, filestream, preview

I am working on file previewing in iOS. I have tried using UIWebview to load the data and UIDocumentInteractionViewController. However, these methods won't work well with large files.

I was thinking of using FileStreams InputStream/OutputStream to preview files.

How can I use UIWebview to preview file from an InputStream.

Would love to know a good approach to this problem?.